# Перевод функции из C на Delphi (вывод данных)

Tags: c, delphi

Есть код, функции написанный на С, буду благодарен за помощь в переводе ее на Delphi (Pascal).

```
void f_print(void *uctx, const char *data, size_t length)
{
    static int state   = 0;
    const char *s      = data;
    const char *prefix = (const char *)uctx;

    while (length != 0)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case 0: 
            { 
                if (prefix != NULL) printf(prefix); 
                state = 1; 
                s = data; 
                break; 
            }
            case 1:
            {
                size_t l = 0;

                while (*data != '\r' && *data != '\n' && length != 0) 
                    data++, length--, l++;

                if (l != 0)
                {
                    fwrite(s, 1, l, stdout);
                }

                if (*data == '\r' || *data == '\n') state = 2;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                if (*data == '\r' || *data == '\n') data++, length--;
                else 
                {
                    fwrite("\r\n", 1, 2, stdout);
                    state = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Начал делать данную функцию (метод) на делфи:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Print(AUctx: Pointer; AData: PAnsiChar; ALength: SIZE_T);
var
  S                                   : PAnsiChar;
  prefix                              : PAnsiChar;
  state                               : Byte;
  L                                   : Byte;
begin

  state := 0;
  prefix := AUctx;
  S := AData;

  while (ALength <> 0) do
    begin
      case state of
        0: begin
             if prefix <> nil then
               FrmMain.mmoOutput.Lines.Add(prefix);
             s := AData;
             state := 1;
           end;

        1: begin
             l := 0;
           {
             КАК ТУТ РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ КОД ?
           }
           end;

        2: begin
          {
            КАК ТУТ РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ КОД ?
          }   
           end;
      end;
    end;

end;
```

Не знаю, как правильно реализовать код на делфи, для case (state) = 1 и 2. Может еще у меня есть в написанном коде, проблемы? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как то так? Вроде ж переписать надо, как есть, разница то никакой.
доступ к значению по указателю через `^`. инкременты и декременты через `inc` и `dec`. Указатели тоже можно инкрементировать. Перенос строки и возврат каретки через коды `#13#10`.

```
while aLength <> 0 do begin

    case state of
        1 : begin
            l := 0;
            while( (adata^ <>  #13) and (adata^ <> #10) and (alength <> 0)) do  begin
                inc(adata);
                dec(alength);
                inc(l);
            end;

            if( l <> 0) then begin
                write(copy(s, 1, l));
            end;

            if( (adata^ = #13) or (adata^ = #10)) then state := 2;

            break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

*зы: `site_t` это беззнаковое целое, то есть `Cardinal` в терминах delphi.

Некоторой проблемой будет использование `static` переменной в методе. В delphi нет аналогов таким вещам. То есть в вашем си-шном варианте, переменная `state` устанавливается в 0 только при первом вызове, а затем ее значение сохраняется между вызовами функции. В своей delphi-коде вы ее инициализируете нулем при каждом запуске.*

зы2: Для замены статичной переменной метода, можно использовать либо глобальную переменную, и инициализировать ее где-нибудь в `initialize`-секции, либо создать некоторый тип данных (record), в котором создать классовое поле (`class var`). Тут оно само нулем станет. Жаль, это нельзя сделать для inline-типов в процедуре.

Comment: Как еще реализовать case 2: , Спасибо!

Comment: @ИндиПутный у вас аналогичные куски кода есть в и 1-м `case`, неужели не сложите 2+2 ?

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Меня смутил синтаксис С не совсем привык к нему... Ответ закрываю, спасибо за помощь!